# how to Calculate Leave Duration?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table TmLeave with the below structure:

```
EmployeeID     StartDate     EndDate     LeaveDuration
------------------------------------------------------
0001            20/07/2014    20/07/2014       1
0001            21/07/2014    21/07/2014       1
0001            22/07/2014    22/07/2014       1
0001            24/07/2014    25/07/2014       2
0001            26/07/2014    26/07/2014       1
0001            28/07/2014    30/07/2014       3
```

I want to calculate the sum of LeaveDuration values for consecutive days for an employee and my result set should look like below:

```
EmployeeID     StartDate     EndDate     LeaveDuration
------------------------------------------------------
0001            20/07/2014    22/07/2014       3
0001            24/07/2014    26/07/2014       3
0001            28/07/2014    30/07/2014       3
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version? In 2012 you can use the `lag()` function for this.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I'm surprised that m$sql can work with this date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below answer done using `CTE`:

```
;With T as (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.EmployeeID order by a.StartDate) RN, 
        *
    From tbl a
)
,T1 as (
    select 
        *, 
        RN CN 
    from T 
    where RN=1

    union all

    select 
        T.*, 
        case when T1.EndDate+1=T.StartDate then CN else T.RN end 
    from T join T1 on T.RN=T1.RN+1
) 
select 
    EmployeeID, 
    MIN(StartDate) StartDate, 
    MAX(EndDate) EndDate, 
    SUM(LeaveDuration) LeaveDuration 
from T1
group by EmployeeID, CN
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91e38/1)